# How do i handle Errors in node express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

Is there a way to add middleware or app.use() to catch all possible errors?

I have tried some global try-catch approaches but it looks so fragile.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be like below

Place below code in

> server.js
> or index.js

```
   class AppError extends Error {
    constructor(message, statusCode) {
        super(message);

        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.status = `${statusCode}`.startsWith('4') ? 'fail' : 'error';
        this.isOperational = true;

        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    }
}
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
    next(new AppError(`Can't find ${req.originalUrl} on this server!`, 404));
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
    err.status = err.status || 'error';

    res.status(err.statusCode).json({
        status: err.status,
        message: err.message
    });
});
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Middleware 1 called.")
    console.log(req.path)
    next() // calling next middleware function or handler
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Route handler called.")
    res.send("Hello world!") // response sent back – no more middleware called
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle your errors like this:

```
res.status(500).send({ msg: 'Wrong email' })
```

And you can change the status code to send different type of errors or responses:

```
res.status(404).send({ msg: 'Not found' })
res.status(200).send({ msg: 'successful' })
```